# Is it possible to route all traffic on my home network, through one (VPN connected) Linux machine?

Tags: networking, openvpn, vpn

I've been tinkering with Pi-Hole, routing DNS requests and ad-blocking through my main machine in my home network. That got me thinking; could I route all traffic through this PC and utilise the VPN connection there for all clients on the network?

I've looked the option of an expensive OpenVPN enabled router, but if it's possible on my Linux box that would be ideal.

Any help or pointers are much appreciated.

Regards,

Al

Answer (score 0):

your problem looks simple, I think that this [tutorial](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Linux_Router_with_VPN_on_a_Raspberry_Pi) will help you

and this [article](https://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html) is also helpful, just set up your openvpn then replace the `eth0` and `eth1` in the article with your network interface and your vpn interface *(usually tun0)*